# Como criar uma publicação temporária que se apaga automaticamente depois de um tempo

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Eu utilizo a plataforma **Wordpress** e até agora não consegui encontrar um plugin que possibilite a criação de publicações temporárias.

Alguém tem conhecimento de algum plugin ou código que possa fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Existe um plugin para isso chamado: **[Post Expirator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/)**

O plugin **Post Expirator** permite ao usuário definir datas de validade (ou datas de expiração) para ambos, **posts** e **páginas**. Para além dessa opção, podes também optar por alterar as categorias de uma publicação após a data de expiração.

> **Nota:** Se optares por alterar a categoria da publicação, a ação padrão de mudar o status será ignorada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parabéns aí, dá gosto ver post em bom português e bem formatado. E de primeira, *no edits*.

Comment: Obrigado @brasofilo =)